# How to transform CGAL surface mesh vertices?

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a matrix 4d which combines rotation and translation. I also have cgal's surface mesh. What would be the efficient and clean way to transform the surface mesh vertices using my 4d matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::transform()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PkgPolygonMeshProcessingRef.html#ga6a0a99788b1f8014d38fd9ef8fe7d746) which should be doing exactly what you want.